# Javascript querySelectorAll data attribute value not equal to

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

My HTML tags have a `[data-value]` attribute which can be 0, 1, 2 and so on..

If I want to get the elements whose `[data-value]` is not equal to 0, how do I write my query selector?

I tried the following but they don't work:

```
element.querySelectorAll("not[data-value='0']");
element.querySelectorAll("[data-value!='0']");
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To avoid selecting other divs, use `div[data-value]:not([data-value="0"])`:

```js
console.log(
    document.querySelectorAll('div[data-value]:not([data-value="0"])')
);
```

```html
<div data-value="-1">0</div>
<div data-value="0">0</div>
<div data-value="1">1</div>
<div data-value="2">2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

This selects all divs with data-value and its value is NOT 0.

Comment: but the output is 0 0 1 2 3, that means it is selecting all of the divs

Answer (score 10):

Use the selector string `'div:not([data-value="0"])'`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div:not([data-value="0"])')
  .forEach(div => console.log(div));
```

```html
<div data-value="0">0</div>
<div data-value="1">1</div>
<div data-value="2">2</div>
```

You can't use `[attrib!=value]` in vanilla Javascript/CSS, unfortunately, you have to use `:not` instead. (though, you *can* use `[attrib!=value]` in jQuery)

To select `<div>`s which have additionally have a `data-value` attribute, but have one which is not `0`, add `[data-value]` after the initial `div` in the selector string:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-value]:not([data-value="0"])')
  .forEach(div => console.log(div));
```

```html
<div data-value="0">0</div>
<div data-value="1">1</div>
<div data-value="2">2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: This selector will return also the tags without data-value attribute, isn't it?

Comment: @mark uy: Yes, but it works the same way in jQuery.

Comment: @markuy See edit, you just need another `[data-value]`